# ´No data to display´ Using Fusioncharts with Tcl

Tags: tcl, fusioncharts

I have problems creating the XML string. I only see the message ´No data to display´. In my .tcl file I have:

```
set strXMLgrafico "<graph caption='Distribucion Normal de Rendimiento Academico' subCaption='(Curso Administracion de Proyectos I)' xAxisName='Promedio' yAxisName='Densidad de Probabilidad' yAxisMaxValue='1'  divLineColor='91AF46' divLineAlpha='30' alternateHGridAlpha='6' canvasBorderColor='666666' baseFontColor='000000' lineColor='91AF46' numVDivlines='2' showAlternateVGridColor='0' anchorSides='2' anchorRadius='15' showValues='1'>"
    set strXML " "
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $datos]} {incr i} { 
     set strXMLdatos [ concat "<set name='[lindex $datos $i]' value='[lindex $datos $i]' />" ]
     append strXML $strXMLdatos 
    }
    set listaDatos [concat $strXMLgrafico $strXML "</graph>"]
```

And then I call the string listaDatos in the .adp file

```
var barras = new FusionCharts("../indicadores/flash/FCF_Line.swf","barras", "600","300");
barras.setXMLData("@listaDatos@");
barras.render("chartdiv1");
```

This is the code when I click on "View source code" in the browser:

> barras.setXMLData("&lt graph caption='Distribucion Normal de
>   Rendimiento Academico' subCaption='(Curso Administra...

I tried changing characters, i.e. < for

> ´&#60´; , lt

and nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need '@' before and after "listaDatos" ?

Comment: The Tcl code looks OK. It doesn't need that `concat` inside the loop, but it is Mostly Harmless. Sounds like something _not shown to us_ is treating the XML fragment produced as a string that needs quoting applied to it…

Comment: Yes, listaDatos needs the @´s. And I erased the concat. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to tell the adp not to quote the listaDatos variable. Try changing the line in the adp to this:

```
barras.setXMLData("@listaDatos;noquote@");
```